# How to programmatically access iptables?

Tags: linux, gnu, iptables

Is there a way we can query iptables programmatically without making use of shell script? I don't have liberty of using shell script to run iptables command and grep output. Is there a native (API) level access to iptables using GNU C? At the bare minimum I would like to query default policy of iptables.

I was hoping to use /proc file system but I don't think its [implemented yet.](http://www.lowth.com/rope/ProcFileSystem)

Comment: The usual answer to such question is to try `strace`-ing or `ltrace`-ing the command you want, e.g. `strace iptables -L`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically manage iptables rules on the fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109553/how-can-i-programmatically-manage-iptables-rules-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like there isn't any way and it's been acknowledged by Netfilter group.

See SO question, [How can I programmatically manage iptables rules on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109553/how-can-i-programatically-manage-iptables-rules-on-the-fly)

Comment: What about requesting more modest info: If I just want to know then number of rules in table filter, chain FORWARD?

Answer (score 6):

You can interface with the `iptables` library called **`libiptc`**.

That's how I have created my Perl interface to `iptables`: [CPAN IPTables::libiptc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPTables::libiptc)

But the `libiptc` library only gives you an API to the basic *chain* structures.
Accessing and parsing the individual *rules* is a bit more complicated, as it depends on `dyn-loading` the shared libs of the individual *target/match* modules.

My approach in my [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPTables::libiptc) is that I have linked with `do_command()` from `iptables.c`, for doing *rule* changes.

**Another thing you need to know is**:

That a single `iptables` call, perform these actions:

1. Copy the entire ruleset from the kernel to userspace
2. Parse it with `libiptc`
3. Perform one or several changes (usually just one change via iptables cmd)
4. Transform it to kernel blob format, by libiptc
5. Copy the entire (new) ruleset from userspace to kernel.

Thus, a heavy process, if you only make a single change each time.
But you can also use this to your advantage, and perform many changes at once, and have these appear as a single atomic change, by/for the kernel.

Comment: Notice, that the command: `iptables-restore` uses the smart approach of doing many changes before submitting the changes to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, by `ltrace`-ing `iptables -L`, I fould that there is an `iptables-dev` package on my Debian/Sid with [libipq](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libipq) and related libraries. You probably might want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the proc-fileystem under /proc/net/
Have a look at http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-3.html#ss3.9 and look for proc (in different questions)

Answer (score 0):

Hm why shouln't he look into the sources of iptables to get an idea? I can not see why one would use strace to figure it out if the sources just contains the needed code.