# How to implement packet shaping or QOS using c++ library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I have a question related to networking using c++ in linux.

**Description**

I am trying to build a client management system that can control bandwidth to each clients. I have tried to search for answers in many places. I end up in LARTC. I think LARTC provides a scripting mechanism to do it. But I want to know pure programming methodology or header file in c programming language (that can communicate to network stack- if any) in linux(Ubuntu 13.04 beta).

Example: I found a header file namely Qos.h in C++. Net (for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of related questions:

I dont think that out-of-the box solution exists (in a sense of C/C++ API).

[How can I programmatically manage iptables rules on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109553/how-can-i-programmatically-manage-iptables-rules-on-the-fly)

[How to programmatically access iptables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603134/how-to-programmatically-access-iptables)